# Problem in giving path for the JavaScript file in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this question seems like the non-sense type, but I really want to know if it is possible.

Actually, I am trying to give the path of JavaScript in HTML file which is in another folder and I only know about how to go one folder up by using

```
../
```

But you can see in the image that where is my HTML file named "current.html" is situated and where is my javascript file named "index.js" is situated. So is there anybody who can help me in this case?

Here is the [link for the Image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19G3Bj53l0MAR41EdGEGWRuc7-4k6qeta)

Comment: is `Public` your web root?

Comment: each time you put a `../` you go up one level. Go up as many level as you need to reach the first common node (in your example three levels) and then add the folder to reach the target

Comment: You know how to go up one folder. It should be pretty obvious how to go up one folder *again*.

Comment: @WillardSolutions yes, it is.   But I would also like to read your reply in case if my answer is no.

Comment: ../../Functions/index.js

Comment: You are currently (in index.html) in the HTML folder, so you need to go back to `Public` and then go back to your `main folder`, so you need to use `..` twice. The final path is then `../../Functions/index.js`

Comment: If `public` is your root, your HTML cannot access index.js.  It is outside the webroot

Comment: @WillardSolutions So is there not any way for this problem

Comment: No. You need to move your JS files into your web root.  In your case, index.js needs to be under `public`

Comment: @WillardSolutions but I want to give a button in "current.html" file for "logout". So, that's why I want to use "index.js file.

Comment: Why would the location of your JS file preclude you from doing that?

Comment: @WillardSolutions I just want to use the same javascript file for login and logout function, and in firebase, we have to use "index.js" file for these functionalities(as I know), but maybe you correct me, if I am wrong here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188067/discussion-between-kapil-sharma-and-willardsolutions).

Comment: You're trying to solve a very different problem than this question addresses. Create a new question with your login/logout code and be specific about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`../` to go up a folder and `/functions` to go inside the functions folder

`../../Functions/index.js`
look out that localhost usually isn't case sensitive but servers usually are

Answer (score 0):

If Main Folder is the root of your website:

```
/Functions/index.js
```

Answer (score -1):

If the entire folder structure is hosted:

```
../../Functions/index.js
```